# Firing different requests in every iteration

Tags: jmeter

I am using JMeter to simulate 10 users firing requests every 40 seconds. I have created 100 different requests but after every 40 seconds, each user is firing all 100 requests. I want to make it in such a way that after every 40 seconds, each user only fires 1 request and that request has to be different from the previous request. I would like to know what should I use to achieve this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You can put your 100 requests in i.e. CSV file and use [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) to iterate through them

To limit/shape the load you can use [Constant Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer) or [Constant Throughput Timer](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer) depending on your use case.